# Laravel logging out automatically

Tags: session, logout, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3 and Laravel's default authentication system. After login the page redirect to the welcome page. But if I click on any other link the page redirect to the login page.

I tried using database for session driver, the result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found the problem. The application is logging out because I used `Auth::logout()` in blade.

```
<li>
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="{{ Auth::logout() }}">
        <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout
    </a>
</li>
```

In Laravel 5.3 `url(/logout)` is no longer working. So, I used `Auth::logout()` but the problem is `logout()` method on `Auth` facade is  clearing the authentication information from user's session whenever the page load.

**Extra:**

To get a logout link in application I am using this method:

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
        <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
        Logout
    </a>
    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    </form>    
</li>
```